# "WITH AS" Working in Postgres but not in H2 dabatabse

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, h2, common-table-expression

I am writing a single query to insert data into 2 tables using "WITH AS". The query works fine on Postgres but on H2 database it is throwing syntax error.

I have 2 tables.
Table 1 has 2 columns -- a Primary Key **table1_ID** and a **table1_value** column.
Table 2 has 3 columns -- a PK **table2_Id** and **table2_value** and **table1_id** as Foreign key.

The query is like this:

```
WITH ins as (
    INSERT INTO table_1 (table1_value) VALUES ("table1_value")
    RETURNING table1_ID as t1_id
   )
   INSERT INTO table_2 (table2_value, tab1_id) VALUES ("table2_value", (SELECT t1_id FROM ins));
```

This query works fine on Postgres but on H2 DB it throws syntax error with a message

> "; expected "(, WITH, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement

Comment: Correct, that's a non-standard extension by Postgres and won't work with other databases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you suggest an alternative to this?

Comment: Use two inserts. The first one can return the generated ID, which the second one then uses. How exactly you access the generated ID depends on your programming language. So this becomes a question for that, rather than a SQL question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hadatabase reference link:
http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries
http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html?highlight=insert&search=insert#firstFound

---

see **Compatibility** section: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

> INSERT conforms to the SQL standard, except that the RETURNING clause
> is a **PostgreSQL extension**, as is the ability to use WITH with INSERT,
> and the ability to specify an alternative action with ON CONFLICT.
> Also, the case in which a column name list is omitted, but not all the
> columns are filled from the VALUES clause or query, is disallowed by
> the standard.

Comment: So is there an alternative to the current approach?

Comment: you can google h2 database merge.  I don't know h2 database, but I think this problem can be solved step by step.